# K&R 1.9 \\ exceeding the scope of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, kernighan-and-ritchie, character-arrays

I'm having a difficult time understanding this function:

```
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c,i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

I will try to explain my doubts with an example input of `0123456789\n` (for a total of 11 characters).

In this example `lim=10` and `s[]` is set to `line[10]` (from the declaration of the calling argument of `getline`).

When the loop has finished running trhough `++i` these are the values: `i==9`, `s[0]==0, ..., s[9]==9`, `c=='\n'` (because `getchar` executes as part of the check condition).

Then the `if` checks positive and `s[9]` is set to `'\n'` while `i` is raised to `10`.

Finally, `s[10]` is set to `'\0'`, but `s[10]` doesn't exist!

Also, `s[]` later prints to `012345678` with the value of `s[9]` being reserved for one between `'\n'` and `'\0'`.

Where is `'\0'` being stored? I know it's there somewhere because later another function makes use of it to check for the end of the array.

Comment: just use a debugger to inspect the array.

Comment: `getchar()` would not be called as part of the check condition when `i==9` because the test fails when the `i<lim-1` test is done.  The rules of C's evaluation of the `&&` operator mean that the latter parts of the test are not evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the chcek `i<lim-1`, if `lim` is 10, `i` will never become `9` inside `for` loop, it can reach a max value of `8`, before the condition check fails.

After `i` becomes `9`, the first part of the `for` loop condition check fails, and the control comes out of loop [without executing `getchar()` for that iteration).

So, upto `s[8]` is read and at `s[9]`, the `\0` is stored.

Comment: @gopi: when `i` becomes 9 it drops out of the `for` loop before calling `getchar()`, so `c` is not `'\n'`.

Comment: @Michael_Burr Thank you for your note! (I'd upvote you of I could).